# Airflow: How to pass variable from python script executed by BaseOperator to on_failure_callback arg in DAG

Tags: python, callback, airflow

I have simple DAG with one task which needs to be dockerized. Based on run of that script which have variable1 inside it I need to provide it to callback function created in the DAG file. How this could be solved?

```
with DAG(
    dag_id=DagName, 
    default_args=default_args, 
    schedule_interval='12 * * * *',
    on_failure_callback=callback_function(variable1),

) as dag:

first_task = BaseOperator(
    name='first-task',
    image=image,
    cmd=f'python script1.py {arg1}'.
)
```

Answer (score -1):

[XComs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.1/concepts.html?highlight=xcom#xcoms) can be used for passing the variable. Basically XComs help communication between tasks by passing massages.

Your task will push a value to `xcom` and the `on_failure_callback` function will pull the value from `xcom`.

Here is a simple example (using `PythonOperator` for simplicity):

```py
def on_failure(context):
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.info("############## on_failure_callback ##############")
    my_variable = context["ti"].xcom_pull(task_ids="", key="my_variable")
    logger.info(my_variable)


def do_something(**context):
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.info("############## do_something_func ##############")
    context["ti"].xcom_push(key="my_variable", value="hello")
    raise Exception("make the task fail")


with DAG(dag_id="example_dag",
         start_date=days_ago(2),
         schedule_interval='0 */1 * * *',
         on_failure_callback=on_failure) as dag:
    t1 = PythonOperator(task_id="task_1",
                        python_callable=do_something,
                        provide_context=True)
```